# Use $request in view composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I trying to write a view composer,

```
class CountryCodeComposer
{

    function compose($view)
    {
         $code = substr(file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/' . $request->getClientIp() . '/country'), 0, 2);
       $view->with('code', $code);
    }
}
```

but this code show error `Undefined variable: request`,

How can I pass `$request` to compose method ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `$request->getClientIp()` with `request()->getClientIp()`

Comment: thanks. I was getting the error message: `on-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::server() should not be called statically` and this solved it.

Answer (score 6):

If someone is looking for an alternative of global `request()` helper function. Here is an example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

/**
 * Connect Http Request class
 */
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ExampleComposer
{   
    private $request;

    /**
     * Pass $request
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
       $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        // use $this->request
    }
}
```